# How retrieve two classes Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

i am green in flutter and i have quick question, would like to make retrieve two classes `SearchBar() & HomeView()`, but it only allows to retrieve one class. I understand that something is missing, i would like to hear your suggestions in order to learn it better.

```
    return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text(title),
          actions: <Widget>[
            IconButton(
                icon: Icon(
                  Icons.add_box,
                  color: Colors.white,
                ),
                onPressed: () {
                  Navigator.push(
                      context,
                      MaterialPageRoute(
                          builder: (context) =>
                              AddBookPage(uid: this.widget.uid)));
                })
          ],
        ),
        body: SearchBar(),
        body: HomeView(),
        drawer: NavigateDrawer(uid: this.widget.uid));
  }
```

[Here is the picture how i would like make it look like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T8YO6.jpg)

[I get Search Bar overflowed by Infinity pixels on the bottom](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fijgP.jpg)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `Column`:

```
Scaffold(
  body: Column(
    children: [
      SearchBar(),
      SizedBox(height: 20),
      Expanded(
        child: HomeView(),
      )
    ],
  ),
  // ... your other code
)
```

Comment: Thanks @CopsOnRoad for the help i really appreciate it, but i get another error with 'SearchBar()' as it overflowed by Infinity pixels on the bottom. I add additional screen shot as well

Comment: @Chorche I don't know what's in your `SearchBar`. However, to test the above code, wrap your `SearchBar` in a `SizedBox` and give that box a `height` of say `200`.

Answer (score 1):

Using a `Column` may be the best way.
The overflow error is probably caused by the `SearchBar()` widget not having a defined height. A `Column` widget can't have a child with infinite height.